# How to open a file in ternary in python?

Tags: python, ternary

I am an amateur python coder. I was wondering if there was a way to open a file in ternary? It would really help to know soon. Something like this but ternary:

```
with open("C:/Users/jfamily/Documents/NJ_Science_Fair/binary_open_test.txt", 
"rb") as binaryfile :
data = bytearray(binaryfile.read())
print(data)
```

Comment: What does "open in ternary" even mean? Computers don't work in ternary. What's the content of the file, and how does it represent ternary data?

Comment: I know you can open file data in binary in python, but I want to know whether or not you could do that except opening the data in ternary and not binary.

Comment: why do you need ternary?

Comment: Binary mode just means that data returned from calls to read are bytes, which are sequences of 8-bit values, as opposed to text characters in a string which can be composed of one or more bytes each (in Python 3). So a "ternary" mode really would make no sense...

Comment: I am encoding and decoding photos into DNA for my Science Fair project. I am currently decoding and I need to open the image file in ternary.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs about open

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

> As mentioned in the Overview, Python distinguishes between binary and
>   text I/O. Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode
>   argument) return contents as bytes objects without any decoding. In
>   text mode (the default, or when 't' is included in the mode argument),
>   the contents of the file are returned as str, the bytes having been
>   first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the
>   specified encoding if given.

So really "binary" here means bytes. Those bytes could contain data in some kind of ternary encoding, but you'd likely still open the file as binary and decode them to your ternary spec yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such facility in Python.  The language supports binary because it's a common file format; ternary is not.

Of course, if *you* find it useful, I suggest that you write a ternary package of your own.

Comment: Binary isn't exactly a *file format*. It's more like the complete absence of a file format - the computer doesn't interpret the data in any way.

Comment: @Aran-Fey 's comment, here, is I think the best answer to this question